# vim-powerline shows a weird red color in the left side

Tags: vim-plugin, vim-powerline

I don't know what is wrong with my vim-powerline. A unexpected red bar on the left side of powerline in Macvim, whereas it doesn't appear when I use vim in terminal.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Both Macvim and vim share the same vimrc file. How can I solve this issue in macvim?

Answer (score 0):

> Lokaltog/vim-powerline is outdated and no longer maintained.

https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1745

---

I solved my version of this problem by removing vim-powerline, installing [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) via `pip install --user powerline-status` and adding the following to my .vimrc file:

```
set rtp+=$HOME/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/powerline/bindings/vim/
set laststatus=2
```